# How prove this matrix $B^{-1}-A^{-1}$ is positive-semidefinite matrix,if $A-B$ is positive matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-calculus, matrix-decomposition

**Question:**

> Let $A,B$ be positive $n\times n$ matrices, and assume that $A-B$ is also a positive definite matrix.
>
> Show that
> $$B^{-1}-A^{-1}$$ is a positive definite matrix too.

My idea: since $A,B$ be positive matrix,and then exist non-singular matrices $P,Q$,such
$$A=P^{-1}\operatorname{diag}{(a_{1},a_{2},\cdots,a_{n})}P$$
$$B=Q^{-1}\operatorname{diag}{(b_{1},b_{2},\cdots,b_{n})}Q$$
where $a_{i},b_{i}>0$

Comment: Positive element-wise or positive definite?

Comment: It does not work for $n = 1$.

Comment: It's not true that you can always choose the same $P$ for diagonalizing $A$ and $B$, it's only if they commute. And are you sure you don't mean negative semidefinite?

Answer (score 7):

As $A$ and $B$ positive definite they have positive definite square roots: 
$$
A=A_1^2,\,\, B=B_1^2.
$$
[If $A=U^*\mathrm{diag}(d_1,\ldots,d_2)U$, then $A_1=U^*\mathrm{diag}(d_1^{1/2},\ldots,d_2^{1/2})U$.]

Clearly$^*$,
$$
A-B\ge 0 \Longleftrightarrow B^{-1}_1AB_1^{-1} \ge I,
$$
where $I$ is the unit matrix. Also$^{**}$,
$$
B^{-1}_1AB_1^{-1} \ge I\Longleftrightarrow I \ge B_1A^{-1}B_1 \Longleftrightarrow B^{-1} \ge A^{-1}.
$$

$^*$More specifically, if
$(x,Ax)\ge (x,Bx)$, then $(B_1^{-1}x,AB_1^{-1}x)\ge (B_1^{-1}x,BB_1^{-1}x)$ or
$(B_1^{-1}x,AB_1^{-1}x)\ge (B_1^{-1}x,B_1x)$, for all $x$. But $(B_1^{-1}x,B_1x)=(x,B_1^{-1}B_1x)=(x,x)$ and $(B_1^{-1}x,AB_1^{-1}x)=(x,B_1^{-1}AB_1^{-1}x)$.

$^{**}$If $A\ge I$, then $(x,Ax)\ge(x,x)$, and hence 
$$
(x,x)=(A_1^{-1}x,AA_1^{-1}x)\ge(A_1^{-1}x,A_1^{-1}x)=(x,A^{-1}x).
$$

Comment: What does the notation $(x,Ax)\geq(x,Bx)$ mean? Is that a tuple? 

Also what is the $*$ notation called?

Comment: @Hatshepsut It means that this is true for every vector $x$.

Comment: why $^{**}$If $A\ge I$